# Ubuntu "Server" but with a better terminal?

Tags: command-line

I'm currently using Ubuntu Server installed in VirtualBox for running various server services. The only drawback it posses for me is that I cannot use mouse in the terminal and select/copy/paste stuff.

What would be an alternative in this situation to get a better terminal? I guess Ubuntu Server itself doesn't support mouse, so I'd have to go for Ubuntu Desktop, but it seems like a huge waste of resources to run Unity/Gnome3 in VirtualBox only to have a terminal.

So then I'm wondering whether Xubuntu/Lubuntu would be suitable alternatives, although they still take a lot of time to boot up, etc.

Any ideas how to solve this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use the server directly at all, but rather connect to it from your host. On almost any kind of server, you'll want to have openssh-server installed. Then you just open a terminal on your host and connect to it using ssh. You might want to run a byobu/screen session on the server.

In other words; use your normal terminal emulator and connect to the server.

Comment: The problem is that in this configuration, my host is Windows. And we all know how much that sucks when it comes to this area.

Comment: Then you should be looking for a better terminal for Windows. :) Terminator sounds nice. PuTTY is a good choice, I think.

Answer (score 1):

A minimal X server running at login or when you type `startx` will contain `xterm` that even tough is not the best thing in the world is enough to copy/paste stuff around.

A X server doesn't really use much resources unless its running a desktop on top of it.

If I were you I would clone the server, install X on to the clone and compare resources.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `gpm` mouse server, install it, the start it with

```
sudo service gpm start
```

but cannot say if it works on vbox.